# R: Filtering by First Digit of an Integer

Tags: r, filter

I have long list of Integers (>250k) ranging from 2 digit numbers to 4 digit numbers.  I would like to separate and then filter on the first digit of the integer using R.

SICCode <- c(47, 286, 3231, 93, 854, 153)

My efforts to return 4, 2, 3, 9, 8 and 1 have been thwarted.  I've searched around but can't find exactly what I'm looking for.  Have to believe I'm missing something easy... please be kind!  Thanks

Comment: `as.integer(substr(SICCode, 1, 1))#[1] 4 2 3 9 8 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `substr`

```
as.integer(substr(SICCode, 1, 1))
#[1] 4 2 3 9 8 1
```

Comment: Thank you akrun...  I was trying with nchar and complicating things...

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom filter function `f` like below

```
f <- Vectorize(function(x) {
  repeat {
    if (x<10) return(x)
    x <- x%/%10
  }
})
```

then

```
> f(SICCode)
[1] 4 2 3 9 8 1
```